# React router error, implement match interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My issue is, that after implementing react router, I don't understand how to re-use component. ! (as stupid it sounds..)

routes.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { Subscription } from "./components/Subscription";
import { Billing } from "./components/Billing";
import { Layout } from "./components/Layout";
import { NavigationMenu } from "./components/NavigationMenu";

export const routes =
    <Router>
        <Layout>
            <NavigationMenu />

            <Redirect from="/" to="/Subscription" />
            <Route exact path="/Subscription" component={Subscription} />
            <Route exact path="/Billing" component={Billing} />
        </Layout>
    </Router>;
```

Subscription.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { CustomerSelection } from "./CustomerSelection";
import { ProfileSelection } from "./ProfileSelection";
import { OrderSubmission } from "./OrderSubmission";
import { FileDownload } from "./FileDownload";
import { VoomConfig } from "../voomconfig";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";
import { SubscriptionLines } from "./SubscriptionLines";

export class Subscription extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, ICustomerState> {
    constructor() {
        super();

        const config: IAppSettings = require("Config");

    ...
    }
}
```

Before implement router  `<Subscription />` component were using `RouteProps` instead of `RouteComponentPros`..

Now, routing seems to be working, but in case I need to `re-use/test my Subscription component` I' am receiving

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Subscription> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }...'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{}>>'.
    Property 'match' is missing in type '{}'.
```

I do understand I need to implement that interface and set props when re-using `<Subscription ....props />`

But as much I've googled, I could not manage to solve this.. :/
All dependency for project.

```
{
  "name": "test_name",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.1.9",
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/jest": "^22.2.0",
    "@types/react": "15.0.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-15": "^1.0.5",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.2",
    "jest-mock-axios": "^1.0.21",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.2",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "primereact": "^1.4.1",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack",
    "debug": "node --debug-brk --inspect ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest -i"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test-shim.js",
      "<rootDir>/test-setup.js"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^Config$": "<rootDir>/appsettings.Development.json"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/test-preprocessor.js"
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/*.(ts|tsx|js)"
    ]
  }
}
```

*** IF I explained something wrong, or something is missing, just let me know. ! Huge thanks in advance. !

Edit:

```
interface RouteComponentProps<P> {
  match: match<P>;
  location: H.Location;
  history: H.History;
  staticContext?: any;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try to understand the basic around `Typescript` and React with `Typescript` as you are working with it.

```
class Subscription extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, ICustomerState> {...}
```

With that component declaration, you tell Typescript that `Subscription` component having the generic `RouteComponentProps` as the prop types. I assume that you are using `react-router` ver 3, `RouteComponentProps` is declared as below with this version:

```
interface RouteComponentProps<P, R> {
    location: Location;
    params: P & R;
    route: PlainRoute;
    router: InjectedRouter;
    routes: PlainRoute[];
    routeParams: R;
}
```

With that declaration, `location`, `params` and so on are **required** props, therefore Typescript will require you to provide these props for your `Subscription` component wherever you want to use it.

The error you receive happens when you try to use this component without providing these props, for example:

`<Subscription />`

It's a expected behaviour from `Typescript`.

If you want to re-use the logic or presentation inside `Subscription` component, create another component for it and don't use `RouteComponentProps` for that component props. You can then use it inside the `Subscription` component (the route component).

Comment: I have edited original post ( added interface RouteComponentProps declaration)

Regarding your answer, does than mean, I cannot simply reuse <Subscription /> component. ? Could I somehow just "build" required props. ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot use `<Subscription />` once you declare `RouteComponentProps` as its props. You can always declare your component props yourself, however, it might not be type compatible with `react-router` `Route.component` attribute. I believe the react-router `Route` require the component passed to its props `component` having the prop types equal to or extended from `RouteComponentProps`. The better way to work around it is to wrap the reusable part into another component.

Comment: yes.. exactly  the answer I needed, and yes, without RouteComponentProps routing does not work.. 

Thank you good sir.! :)